# Do I need some extra steps to register the changes to the DeviceContext?

Tags: winapi, rust, gdi

So I was trying to make a win32 overlay with rust, but after some time I realized that due to poor way I organized my code some things were too difficult to add - and I'm trying to rewrite it in a more fitting manner. My particular problem however is that now in rewritten state (using a mem dc for double buffering now), I cant get my bitmap to appear on the screen.

I cant seem to pinpoint the problem as GetLastError returns 0.

My current script for window is below:

```rust
use crate::static_helpers::win32_string;

use winapi::um::winuser::{WM_PAINT, WM_TIMER, WNDCLASSW, DefWindowProcW, ShowWindow, SW_NORMAL, WS_POPUP, WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, WS_EX_LAYERED, WS_EX_TOPMOST, WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW, WS_VISIBLE, CreateWindowExW, RegisterClassW, CS_HREDRAW, CS_OWNDC, CS_VREDRAW, SetLayeredWindowAttributes, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED, LWA_COLORKEY, ReleaseDC, InvalidateRect, EndPaint, PAINTSTRUCT, BeginPaint, GetClientRect, MSG, GetMessageW, SetTimer, USER_TIMER_MINIMUM, TIMERPROC, GetDC, UpdateWindow};
use winapi::shared::windef::{HWND__, HDC__, HWND, RECT, HDC, HBITMAP, HGDIOBJ};
use std::time::SystemTime;
use winapi::shared::minwindef::{UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM, LRESULT, HINSTANCE};
use std::ptr::null_mut;
use winapi::um::wingdi::{CreateSolidBrush, RGB, DeleteDC, SelectObject, BitBlt, GetStockObject, DC_PEN, SRCCOPY, CreateCompatibleDC, BITMAP, CreateBitmap, CreateCompatibleBitmap, ExtFloodFill};
use winapi::um::libloaderapi::GetModuleHandleW;
use winapi::um::errhandlingapi::GetLastError;


pub struct Overlay {
    window_class: WNDCLASSW,
    // window class stored
    window_handle: *mut HWND__,
    // window handle stored
    mem_dc: Option<*mut HDC__>,
    // buffer dc
    screen_dc: Option<*mut HDC__>,
    // screen dc
    bitmap_bg: HBITMAP,
}


impl Overlay {
    // redirects event handling to default handler
    pub unsafe extern "system" fn proc_msg(hwnd: HWND, msg: UINT, wparam: WPARAM, lparam: LPARAM) -> LRESULT {
        match msg {
            _ => { return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam); }
        }
    }


    // creates new instance
    pub unsafe fn new(class_name: String, window_name: String) -> Self {


        // gets module instance handle to register stuff
        let hinstance = GetModuleHandleW(null_mut());

        // makes window class
        let wnd_class = WNDCLASSW {
            style: CS_HREDRAW | CS_OWNDC | CS_VREDRAW,
            lpfnWndProc: Some(Self::proc_msg),
            hInstance: hinstance as HINSTANCE,
            lpszClassName: win32_string(&class_name).as_ptr(),
            cbClsExtra: 0,
            cbWndExtra: 0,
            hIcon: null_mut(),
            hCursor: null_mut(),
            hbrBackground: CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0)), // brush so repaint works
            lpszMenuName: null_mut(),
        };

        // registers class (returns atom but i don`t need it so far)
        RegisterClassW(&wnd_class);


        /*
         creating window
         transparent style for event pipethrough, toolwindow style hides from alt+tab and task mgr
         popup and visible are to keep it fullscreen with no title bar

         */

        let handle: *mut HWND__ = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_TRANSPARENT | WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW,
                                                  win32_string(&class_name).as_ptr(),
                                                  win32_string(&window_name).as_ptr(),
                                                  WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE,
                                                  0,
                                                  0,
                                                  1919,
                                                  1079,
                                                  null_mut(),
                                                  null_mut(),
                                                  hinstance,
                                                  null_mut(),
        ) as *mut HWND__;


        // getting window dc
        let window_dc = GetDC(handle);

        //make a buffer dc
        let mem_dc = CreateCompatibleDC(window_dc);

        //make bg bitmap and fill it to change size of dc
        let bmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(mem_dc, 1920, 1080);
        SelectObject(mem_dc, bmp as HGDIOBJ);

        ShowWindow(handle, SW_NORMAL);


        return Self {
            window_class: wnd_class,
            window_handle: handle,
            mem_dc: Some(mem_dc),
            screen_dc: Some(window_dc),
            bitmap_bg: bmp,
        };
    }


    pub unsafe fn make_transparent(&mut self) {
        ShowWindow(self.window_handle, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED); // maximize
        SetLayeredWindowAttributes(self.window_handle, RGB(0, 0, 0), 0, LWA_COLORKEY); // set transparent
    }

    pub fn die(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            match self.mem_dc {
                Some(mut hDC) => {
                    DeleteDC(hDC);
                }
                _ => {}
            }

            match self.screen_dc {
                Some(mut hDC) => {
                    ReleaseDC(self.window_handle, hDC);
                }
                _ => {}
            }
        }
    }


    // takes anything which takes mutable dc, and handle - and returns bool
    pub unsafe fn do_loop<T1: FnMut(*mut HWND, *mut HDC__) -> bool>(&mut self, mut cb: T1) {
        let mut rc: RECT = RECT::default();

        loop {
            let mut msg: MSG = std::mem::uninitialized(); // later switch to zeroed
            if GetMessageW(&mut msg as *mut MSG, self.window_handle, 0, 0).is_positive() {

                //prep dc canvas
                ExtFloodFill(self.mem_dc.unwrap(), 1920, 1080, RGB(0, 0, 0), FLOODFILLBORDER);

                // passing window handle and buffer dc
                if cb(&mut self.window_handle, self.mem_dc.unwrap()) {
                    // if returned true - change current screen to buffer dc


                    BitBlt(self.screen_dc.unwrap(), 0, 0, 1920, 1080, self.mem_dc.unwrap(), 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
                };
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I attempt to call it in my `main.rs` like follows:

```rust
mod overlay;
mod static_helpers;
mod event_poller;


use static_helpers::TestCat;
use overlay::Overlay;

use winapi::um::libloaderapi::GetModuleHandleW;
use std::ptr::null_mut;
use winapi::shared::windef::HDC;
use winapi::um::wingdi::{BitBlt, SRCCOPY};


fn main() {
    let REDRAW: String = String::from("REDRAW");

    unsafe {
        let mut ticker = event_poller::EventPoller::new();
        ticker.add_event((40, "REDRAW".to_owned()));


        let cat = TestCat::new("C:\\Users\\grass\\Desktop\\codes\\Rust\\catso_v2\\src\\cat2.bmp");


        let mut win: Overlay = Overlay::new("hewwo".to_owned(), "UwU".to_owned());
        win.make_transparent();


        win.do_loop(|handle, hdc| -> bool {
            match (&mut ticker).ask() {
                None => {}
                Some(events) => {
                    if events.contains(&REDRAW) {
                        BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, 100, 100, cat.src, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
                        return true;
                    };
                }
            }


            false
        });

        win.die();
    }
}
```

The timer struct (stored in `ticker` variable) is properly working, but for completeness sake here it is:

```rust
use std::time::SystemTime;

pub struct EventPoller {
    events: Vec::<(u128, SystemTime, String)>,
}

impl EventPoller {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            events: Vec::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn add_event(&mut self, event: (u128, String)) {
        &self.events.push((event.0, SystemTime::now(), event.1));
    }

    pub fn ask(&mut self) -> Option<Vec<String>> {
        let now = SystemTime::now();
        let mut time_passed: u128;

        let mut ret: Vec<String> = Vec::new();

        for i in 0..(&self.events).len() as usize {
            time_passed = now.duration_since((&self.events[i]).1).unwrap().as_millis();
            if time_passed > (&self.events[i]).0 {
                ret.push((&mut self.events[i]).2.clone());
                (&mut self.events[i]).1 = now.clone();
            }
        }

        if ret.len() > 0 {
            Some(ret)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

same goes for a simple `TestCat` struct which only serves for testing purposes (see below):

```rust
pub struct TestCat {
    pub src: *mut HDC__
}

impl TestCat {
    pub unsafe fn new(fname: &str) -> Self {
        let im_handle =  LoadImageW(null_mut(),
                                    win32_string(fname).as_ptr(),
                                    IMAGE_BITMAP,
                                    LR_DEFAULTSIZE as i32,
                                    LR_DEFAULTSIZE as i32,
                                    LR_LOADFROMFILE |  LR_CREATEDIBSECTION);



        let hdc: HDC = CreateCompatibleDC(null_mut());
        SelectObject(hdc,im_handle);
        Self {src: hdc}
    }
}
```

Few things I attempted to do so far are:

- Add a bitmap to a `mem_dc` at the start to ensure it doesn't contain a 1x1 monochrome one.
- call `InvalidateRect` beforehand with and without erase parameter.
- capture WM_DRAW message and preform check for an available update then calling same `BitBlt` within it.

Below is my old code - which works so far, and serves as the source of confusion as I don't really understand what is that key difference:

`transparent_window.rs`:

```rust
#![windows_subsystem = "windows"]

use std::alloc::{alloc, Layout};
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::ffi::{c_void, OsStr};
use std::iter::once;
use std::os::windows::ffi::OsStrExt;
use std::ptr::{null, null_mut};
use std::ptr;
use std::time::SystemTime;

use winapi::shared::minwindef::{HINSTANCE, LPARAM, LRESULT, UINT, WPARAM};
use winapi::shared::windef::{HDC, HDC__, HGDIOBJ, HWND, HWND__, POINT, RECT, SIZE};
use winapi::um::errhandlingapi::GetLastError;
use winapi::um::libloaderapi::GetModuleHandleW;
use winapi::um::wingdi::{AC_SRC_ALPHA, AC_SRC_OVER, BitBlt, BLENDFUNCTION, CreateCompatibleDC, CreatePen, CreateSolidBrush, DC_PEN, DeleteDC, DeleteObject, DEVMODEW, GetClipBox, GetStockObject, PS_SOLID, Rectangle, RGB, SelectObject, SRCCOPY};
use winapi::um::winuser::{BeginPaint, CDS_FULLSCREEN, ChangeDisplaySettingsW, CreateWindowExW, CS_HREDRAW, CS_OWNDC, CS_VREDRAW, CW_USEDEFAULT, DefWindowProcW, DispatchMessageW, EndPaint, GetClientRect, GetDC, GetMessageW, GetParent, GetWindow, GetWindowLongW, GetWindowRect, GW_HWNDNEXT, GWL_EXSTYLE, IMAGE_BITMAP, InvalidateRect, LoadImageW, LR_LOADFROMFILE, LWA_COLORKEY, MSG, PAINTSTRUCT, RDW_ERASE, RDW_INVALIDATE, RDW_UPDATENOW, RedrawWindow, RegisterClassW, ReleaseDC, ScreenToClient, SetLayeredWindowAttributes, SetWindowLongW, ShowWindow, SW_NORMAL, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED, TranslateMessage, ULW_COLORKEY, UpdateLayeredWindow, WM_ERASEBKGND, WM_PAINT, WM_TIMER, WNDCLASSW, WS_EX_APPWINDOW, WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME, WS_EX_LAYERED, WS_EX_STATICEDGE, WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW, WS_EX_TOPMOST, WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, WS_OVERLAPPED, WS_POPUP, WS_POPUPWINDOW, WS_SYSMENU, WS_THICKFRAME, WS_VISIBLE};
use winapi::um::winuser::{WM_KEYDOWN, WM_KEYUP};

fn win32_string(value: &str) -> Vec<u16> {
    OsStr::new(value).encode_wide().chain(once(0)).collect()
}


pub struct BasicWindow {
    window_class: WNDCLASSW,
    window_handle: *mut HWND__,
    mem_DC: Option<*mut HDC__>,
    screen_DC: Option<*mut HDC__>,
    UpdateClock: SystemTime,
    update_frequency: u128,

}

impl BasicWindow {
    pub unsafe extern "system" fn proc_msg(hwnd: HWND, msg: UINT, wparam: WPARAM, lparam: LPARAM) -> LRESULT {
        match msg {
            _ => { return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam); }
        }
    }

    pub fn new(class_name: String, window_name: String) -> Self {
        unsafe {
            let hinstance = GetModuleHandleW(null_mut());

            let wnd_class = WNDCLASSW {
                style: CS_HREDRAW | CS_OWNDC | CS_VREDRAW,
                lpfnWndProc: Some(Self::proc_msg),
                hInstance: hinstance as HINSTANCE,
                lpszClassName: win32_string(&class_name).as_ptr(),
                cbClsExtra: 0,
                cbWndExtra: 0,
                hIcon: null_mut(),
                hCursor: null_mut(),
                hbrBackground: CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0)),
                lpszMenuName: null_mut(),
            };

            let atom = RegisterClassW(&wnd_class);


            let handle: *mut HWND__ = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_TRANSPARENT | WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW,
                                                      win32_string(&class_name).as_ptr(),
                                                      win32_string(&window_name).as_ptr(),
                                                      WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE,
                                                      0,
                                                      0,
                                                      1919,
                                                      1079,
                                                      null_mut(),
                                                      null_mut(),
                                                      hinstance,
                                                      null_mut(),
            ) as *mut HWND__;


            ShowWindow(handle, SW_NORMAL);


            return Self {
                window_class: wnd_class,
                window_handle: handle,
                mem_DC: None,
                screen_DC: None,
                UpdateClock: SystemTime::now(),
                update_frequency: 40,
            };
        }
    }

    pub unsafe fn make_transparent(&mut self) {
        let show_outcome = ShowWindow(self.window_handle, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
        let outcome = SetLayeredWindowAttributes(self.window_handle, RGB(0, 0, 0), 0, LWA_COLORKEY);

        println!("Error: {:?}\nSetLayeredWindowAttributes outcome: {:?}\nShowWindow outcome: {:?}",
                 GetLastError(),
                 outcome,
                 show_outcome);
    }


    pub fn die(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            match self.mem_DC {
                Some(mut hDC) => {
                    DeleteDC(hDC);
                }
                _ => {}
            }

            match self.screen_DC {
                Some(mut hDC) => {
                    ReleaseDC(self.window_handle, hDC);
                }
                _ => {}
            }
        }
    }

    pub unsafe fn do_loop<T1: FnMut() -> Option<(HDC, u32, u32, u32, u32, u32, u32)>>(&mut self,
                                                                                      mut tile_giver: T1) {
        loop {
            let mut msg: MSG = std::mem::uninitialized();
            if GetMessageW(&mut msg as *mut MSG, self.window_handle, 0, 0).is_positive() {
                match msg.message {
                    WM_PAINT => {
                        println!("WM_PAINT!!");

                        let mut ps = PAINTSTRUCT::default();
                        let dc = BeginPaint(self.window_handle, &mut ps);

                        let mut rc = RECT::default();
                        GetClientRect(self.window_handle, &mut rc);


                        let hdi_obj_original = SelectObject(ps.hdc, GetStockObject(DC_PEN as i32));

                        match (tile_giver()) {
                            (Some((hdc, x, y, w, h, x_pos, y_pos))) => {
                                println!("blt returned: {:?}", BitBlt(dc, x_pos as i32, y_pos as i32, w as i32, h as i32, hdc, x as i32, y as i32, SRCCOPY));
                            }
                            _ => {}
                        }


                        SelectObject(ps.hdc, hdi_obj_original);

                        EndPaint(self.window_handle, &ps);

                        InvalidateRect(self.window_handle,
                                       &mut rc,
                                       1);
                    }

                    _ => {}
                }
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

a closure I pass to its `do_loop` method:

```rust
|| -> Option<(HDC, u32, u32, u32, u32, u32, u32)> {
                                let x = sprite.give_tile();
                                sprite.skip();
                                x
                             }
```

where the dc passed is acquired as follows:

```rust
let im_handle =  LoadImageW(null_mut(),
                                        win32_string(fname).as_ptr(),
                                        IMAGE_BITMAP,
                                        LR_DEFAULTSIZE as i32,
                                        LR_DEFAULTSIZE as i32,
                                        LR_LOADFROMFILE |  LR_CREATEDIBSECTION);


            let hdc: HDC = CreateCompatibleDC(null_mut());
            SelectObject(hdc,im_handle);
```

for the sake of providing a reproducible example - here is my `cargo.toml` file:

```
[dependencies]
winapi = "0.3.9"


[features]
default=["winapi/winuser","winapi/minwindef","winapi/windef",
    "winapi/wingdi","winapi/libloaderapi","winapi/errhandlingapi","winapi/impl-default"]
```

I suspect that there is some function to trigger the actual visual update after preforming the bit blit like invalidate rect (I'm aware that `InvalidateRect` just causes WM_PAINT to be fired with or without erasing background, but basically I assume that there might be something I have to call to register the graphical changes outside of `BeginPaint` and `EndPaint`  ). If anyone can help by either pointing the issue, or if you have will and time tell me what the bare minimum drawing procedure outside of WM_PAINT WindowProc match arm should look like.

**Update:**
In response to the feedback I've squeezed unnecessary things out of the code and below is what's left:

```rust
use std::ffi::OsStr;
use std::iter::once;
use std::os::windows::ffi::OsStrExt;
use std::ptr::null_mut;
use std::time::SystemTime;

use winapi::shared::minwindef::HINSTANCE;
use winapi::shared::windef::{HDC__, HWND__};
use winapi::um::errhandlingapi::GetLastError;
use winapi::um::libloaderapi::GetModuleHandleW;
use winapi::um::wingdi::{BitBlt, CreateCompatibleDC, CreateSolidBrush, ExtFloodFill, FLOODFILLBORDER, RGB, SelectObject, SRCCOPY};
use winapi::um::winuser::{CreateWindowExW, CS_HREDRAW, CS_OWNDC, CS_VREDRAW, DefWindowProcW, GetDC, GetMessageW, IMAGE_BITMAP, LoadImageW, LR_CREATEDIBSECTION, LR_DEFAULTSIZE, LR_LOADFROMFILE, LWA_COLORKEY, MSG, RegisterClassW, SetLayeredWindowAttributes, ShowWindow, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED, WNDCLASSW, WS_EX_LAYERED, WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW, WS_EX_TOPMOST, WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, WS_POPUP, WS_VISIBLE};

pub fn win32_string(value: &str) -> Vec<u16> {
    OsStr::new(value).encode_wide().chain(once(0)).collect()
}

unsafe fn make_win() -> (*mut HWND__, *mut HDC__, *mut HDC__) {
    let hinstance = GetModuleHandleW(null_mut());

    let wndclass = WNDCLASSW {
        style: CS_HREDRAW | CS_OWNDC | CS_VREDRAW,
        lpfnWndProc: Some(DefWindowProcW),
        hInstance: hinstance as HINSTANCE,
        lpszClassName: win32_string("uwu").as_ptr(),
        cbClsExtra: 0,
        cbWndExtra: 0,
        hIcon: null_mut(),
        hCursor: null_mut(),
        hbrBackground: CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0)),
        lpszMenuName: null_mut(),
    };

    RegisterClassW(&wndclass);

    let handle: *mut HWND__ = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_TRANSPARENT | WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW,
                                              win32_string("uwu").as_ptr(),
                                              win32_string("owo").as_ptr(),
                                              WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE,
                                              0,
                                              0,
                                              1919,
                                              1079,
                                              null_mut(),
                                              null_mut(),
                                              hinstance,
                                              null_mut(),
    ) as *mut HWND__;

    let mut dc = GetDC(handle);
    let mut c_mem_dc = CreateCompatibleDC(dc);

    return (handle, dc, c_mem_dc);
}

pub unsafe fn make_trasnparent(handle: *mut HWND__) {
    ShowWindow(handle, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(handle, RGB(0, 0, 0),
                               0, LWA_COLORKEY);
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let (handle, dc, c_mem_dc) = make_win();
        make_trasnparent(handle);

        let mut image = CreateCompatibleDC(null_mut());
        SelectObject(image, LoadImageW(null_mut(),
                                       win32_string("C:\\Users\\grass\\Desktop\\codes\\Rust\\catso_v2\\src\\cat2.bmp").as_ptr(),
                                       IMAGE_BITMAP,
                                       LR_DEFAULTSIZE as i32,
                                       LR_DEFAULTSIZE as i32,
                                       LR_LOADFROMFILE | LR_CREATEDIBSECTION));

        let mut msg: MSG = std::mem::uninitialized();
        let mut back_then = SystemTime::now();


        loop {
            if GetMessageW(&mut msg as *mut MSG, handle, 0, 0).is_positive() {
                let now = SystemTime::now();

                if now.duration_since(back_then)
                    .unwrap()
                    .as_millis() > 40 {
                    ExtFloodFill(c_mem_dc, 1920, 1080, RGB(0, 0, 0), FLOODFILLBORDER);

                    BitBlt(c_mem_dc, 0, 0, 100, 100, image, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
                    BitBlt(dc, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, c_mem_dc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
                    back_then = now;
                };
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is still the same and same `cargo.toml` is used.

**Update:**

I've printed out all of the return values for few iterations. So far My loaded image returns a valid handle and so does `CreateCompatibleDC`. Both `BitBlt` return 1, hence they succeed. `GetLastError` always returns zero.

Another thing I've attempted to do is to create a compatible bitmap and select it into `c_mem_dc` to ensure it has an appropriate bitmap size as stated here: [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146498/bitblt-problem-gdi) This however didn't help.

Comment: Complicated code can't help us reproduce the problem, could you please show [a minimal, reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) without private information?

Comment: @SongZhu I hope the squeezed version in the updated question is better. I'm not sure i understand what you mean by private information? The path to the image was the subject of the concern? - Should I provide the image?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry that I don't know much about rust, so I tried the code through C++, and I can indeed reproduce the problem. I think you have a problem with the drawing.

I modified it to the following code, you can refer to it to modify it to rust code:

```
#include <windows.h>
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

HBITMAP bitmap;

int WINAPI WinMain(_In_  HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_  LPSTR szCmdLine, _In_  int iCmdShow)

{
    static TCHAR szAppName[] = TEXT("hello windows");
    WNDCLASS wndclass;
    wndclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_OWNDC | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndclass.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wndclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName;

    if (!RegisterClass(&wndclass))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("This program requires Windows NT!"), szAppName, MB_ICONERROR);
    }

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TRANSPARENT | WS_EX_LAYERED  | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW,
        szAppName,
        TEXT("the hello program"),
        WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE,
        0,
        0,
        800,
        600,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL);

    ShowWindow(hwnd, iCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, RGB(0, 0, 0),
        0, LWA_COLORKEY);


    bitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, L"shaokao.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, LR_DEFAULTSIZE,
        LR_DEFAULTSIZE, LR_LOADFROMFILE | LR_CREATEDIBSECTION);
    MSG msg;        
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        BITMAP bm;
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        HBITMAP hbmOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcMem, bitmap);
        GetObject(bitmap, sizeof(bm), &bm);
        BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
        SelectObject(hdcMem, hbmOld);
        DeleteDC(hdcMem);
        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        break;
    }
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

And it works for me.

Comment: Yeah, I have something along those lines which works for me as well - my issue is that I want to avoid to draw in WindowProc. as I want to introduce some variables accessible through self reference and have control over drawing frequency.

Comment: You get all that and still do all your rendering in the `WM_PAINT` handler. To do that, use a timer (`SetTimer`) and invalidate the entire client area from the `WM_TIMER` message handler. If you want to change the frequency, just `KillTimer` and `SetTimer` using the new interval. You can also associate arbitrary data with a window. For a robust and minimal implementation have a look at the [win-win](https://crates.io/crates/win-win) crate.